# Use the solution to find $A^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus

> **Solve the system $x_2+x_3=a, x_1+x_3=b, x_1+x_2=c$ and use the solution to find $A^{-1}$ where $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 &1 \\1 & 0 & 1 \\1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.**

Attempt:  I can solve the 1st part of the problem.

The solutions are $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(\frac{b+c-a}{2},\frac{c+a-b}{2},\frac{b+a-c}{2})$.

The system can be written as $AX=B$ form. 
Clearly, $A^{-1}$ can be determined by $adj(A)/|A|$, but here this method is not apprpriate.

**How tofind $A^{-1}$ using the solution?**

Comment: Hint: let $B$ be the columns of the identity matrix.

Comment: @MichaelBurr  $B=\begin{bmatrix}a \\b \\c \end{bmatrix}$. Would you please suggest a bit more details what do you want say by "let B be the columns of the identity matrix"

Comment: Use Cramer's rule.

Comment: The first column of $A^{-1}$ is the solution to $Ax=\Bigl[{ 1\atop \textstyle{0\atop 0}}\Bigr ]$.  So find $x$ using your solution with $a=1, b=0, c=0$. Do something similar to find the second and third columns of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Please explore "The first column of $A^{−1}$ is the solution to $Ax=\Bigl[{ 1\atop \textstyle{0\atop 0}}\Bigr ]$"

Comment: $AA^{-1}=I$.  Think of how matrix multiplication works. How do you get the first column of $I$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system in matrix form is $A x = y$ with $y = (a, b, c)^\top$.

An equation for the inverse is $A A^{-1} = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, which can be viewed as three simultaneous equations $A x_{(i)} = e_i$, where $x_{(i)}$ is the $i$-th column vector of $A^{-1}$ and $e_i$ is the $i$-th canonical base vector, which is the $i$-th column vector of $I$.

So you can find $A^{-1}$ by applying your general solution to the three vectors $y = e_i$.

Answer (score 2):

The rows of $A^{-1}$ are just the coefficients of the formulae for the solutions: rewrite these as
$$\begin{aligned}
x_1&=\frac12(-a+b+c)\\
x_2&=\frac12(a-b+c)\\
x_3&=\frac12(a+b-c)
\end{aligned},\quad\text{whence}\qquad A^{-1}=\frac12\begin{bmatrix}-1 &1&1\\
1&-1&1\\
1&1&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Please give me the justification for writing $A^{-1}$ from $x_1, x_2, x_3$.

Comment: @user1942348: it's auto-justified: use this: $AX=B\iff X=A^{-1}B$, and the way matrix multiplication is defined. What else do you want to say?

Comment: Yes I understand.